# Minimal and maximal angular separation of two spheres as viewed from surface of third sphere

Tags: mathematical-optimization, vector

Short version: find the values of theta and phi that make overlapValue (defined below) maximal and the values of theta and phi that make it minimal, given that all other values are constants and subject to the constraint that `-pi/2 < theta < pi/2`

I'd prefer to find a closed form solution and believe one does exist, but will settle for numerical methods if necessary.

```
overlapValue[theta_, phi_] = 

-(-ArcCos[(qr^2 + sx*tx - qr*Cos[phi]*((sx + tx)*Cos[theta] + ty*Sin[theta]))/
      Sqrt[(qr^2 + sx^2 - 2*qr*sx*Cos[phi]*Cos[theta])*(qr^2 + tx^2 + ty^2 - 
         2*qr*Cos[phi]*(tx*Cos[theta] + ty*Sin[theta]))]] + 
   ArcSin[sr/Sqrt[qr^2 + sx^2 - 2*qr*sx*Cos[phi]*Cos[theta]]] + 
   ArcSin[tr/Sqrt[qr^2 + tx^2 + ty^2 - 2*qr*Cos[phi]*(tx*Cos[theta] + 
         ty*Sin[theta])]])/
 (2*ArcSin[sr/Sqrt[qr^2 + sx^2 - 2*qr*sx*Cos[phi]*Cos[theta]]])
```

Long version:

```
(*

We will establish these conditions below, but need to pre-declare them
for simplication.

*)

conds = {sx > 0, Element[{tx, ty, px, py, pz}, Reals], sr > 0, tr > 0, qr > 0,
 theta > -Pi, theta < Pi, phi > -Pi/2, phi < Pi/2};

(*

Let S, T, and Q be three spheres with (positive) radii sr, tr, and qr respectively.

Without loss of generality, we can create Cartesian coordinate system such that:

  - the center of Q is at the origin

  - the center of S is on the positive x axis

  - the center of T is in the xy plane

Thus, we can write the coordinates of the center as follows:

*)

q = {0, 0, 0};
s = {sx, 0, 0};
t = {tx, ty, 0};

(*

where sx is positive, and tx and ty are Real.

*)

(* 

The angular separation between S and T as viewed from any
(real-valued) point {px, py, pz} is:

*)

angsep[px_, py_, pz_] = Simplify[VectorAngle[s-{px, py, pz}, t-{px,
py, pz}], conds];

(* the angular radii of s and t as viewed from any point {px, py, pz} is: *)

angradS[px_, py_, pz_] = Simplify[ArcSin[sr/Norm[s-{px, py, pz}]], conds];
angradT[px_, py_, pz_] = Simplify[ArcSin[tr/Norm[t-{px, py, pz}]], conds];

(*

From any point P (`{px, py, pz}`), we can measure the quantity `val =
((sep-tar)/sar-1)/2` where:

    - `sep` is the angular separation between the centers of S and T as viewed from P
    - `sar` is the angular radius of S as viewed from P
    - `tar` is the angular radius of T as viewed from P

Note that `val` gives us the following:

  - if `val > 0`, the two spheres are not overlapping as viewed from P

  - if `val > -1` and `val < 0`, the two spheres are partially
    overlapping as viewed from P

  - if `val < -1`, one sphere is completely overlapping the other as viewed from P

*)

val[px_, py_, pz_] = Simplify[((angsep[px, py, pz] - angradT[px, py,
pz])/angradS[px, py, pz]-1)/2, conds];

(*

Any point on the surface of sphere Q has spherical coordinates
`{theta, phi, qr}` for some theta ("longitude") between -Pi and Pi and
some phi ("latitude") between -Pi/2 and Pi/2. Converting to
rectangular coordinates, we have:

*)

pointQ[theta_, phi_] = Simplify[{qr*Cos[phi]*Cos[theta],
qr*Cos[phi]*Sin[theta], qr*Sin[phi]}, conds];

(*

Computing val given theta and phi (and calling in overlapValue)

*)

overlapValue[theta_, phi_] = Simplify[val[qr*Cos[phi]*Cos[theta],
qr*Cos[phi]*Sin[theta], qr*Sin[phi]], conds]

(*

Im trying to find the minimum and maximum of overlapValue on the part
of Q that "faces" S (in other words, -Pi/2 < theta < Pi/2).

I tried setting the partials with respect to theta and phi to 0, but
my Mathematica just hung.

*)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `Find the values of theta and phi that make overlapValue maximal and
the values of theta and phi that make it minimal, given that all other
values are constants`

Comment: barrycarter, I suggest you separate your question from the code block, it should be a much better way for others to discern what you are asking. Nice code, though!

Comment: @CATrevillian Good idea, thanks. Done as requested.

Comment: Do you need a method to get a numerical answer once you've set the constants? Or some sort of expression in terms of those constants?

Comment: @MikeY I think a closed-form solution exists, but numerical will be ok if it doesn't. I've edited the question to reflect this

Comment: If I do `res = overlapValue[θ, ϕ]` then I get for `D[res,ϕ]` an expression that is a bunch of stuff multiplied by `Sin[ϕ]`, so `ϕ=0` gives a local min or max.

Comment: @MikeY I actually suspected that, but was unable to prove it-- but i just verified that-- so now its just a problem in one variable, hmm (assuming there aren't any other places the derivative is 0 and phi=0 is just giving us a local min or max or a saddle point)